# <mat-label> is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am new with Angular and Material Design. I am trying to get a form in a dialog.
When compiling, I get lots of errors like `'mat-form-field' is not a known element`

My `app-module.ts`:

```js
    
    import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
    import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
    import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
    import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
    ...
    imports: [
     MatDialogModule,
     MatFormFieldModule,
     MatSelectModule,
     MatInputModule
    ]
```

In my `component.ts` file :

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
    import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
    import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
    import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-bottle-list',
      templateUrl: './bottle-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./bottle-list.component.css']
    })
    export class BottleListComponent implements OnInit {
    
      dataSource: Array<any>;
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['picture', 'name', 'number', 'volume', 'price', 'alcoholType', 'actions'];
      bottle: Bottle;
      passedValues: object;
      marque: string;
      nombre: string;
      volume: string;
      priceInCentsFor1Cl: string;
      alcohol: Alcohol;
      alcohols: Array<any>;
    
      constructor(private bottleService: BottleService, private dialog: MatDialog, private alcoholService: AlcoholService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      addBottle(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddBottle, {
          width: '250px',
          data: { marque: this.marque, volume: this.volume, priceInCentsFor1Cl: this.priceInCentsFor1Cl, nombre: this.nombre, alcohol: this.alcohol }
        });
    
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log('The dialog was closed');
          console.log('All the data', result);
          this.passedValues = result;
        });
      }
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'add-bottle',
      templateUrl: 'add-bottle.html',
    })
    export class AddBottle {
    
      constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddBottle>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }
    
      onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }
```

In my component I then have 2 html files each linked to one of the `@Component` of the ts file.
The `addBottle.html` is my modal and looks like:

```html
       <h2 mat-dialog-title>Ajouter</h2>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>marque</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Votre bouteille" [(ngModel)]="data.marque">
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
```

With several other fields.
I was wondering if the second component was just not carrying about the imports at the beginning of the file? How could I fix these compile errors?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are components declared, in AppModule?
If not, then you want import `MatFormFieldModule` to the module where those component are declared

Comment: Only the first one is declared in it. I'll try to declare the AddBottle too.

Comment: That was the point thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Yuriy
The point was to add

```
import { AddBottle } from './components/bottle-list/bottle-list.component'
```

to my app-module.ts